# How can I choose .NET Framework when create a NUnit Test Project with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, mstest

In Visual Studio 2022, I can not find the .Net Framework option when creating a NUnit Test Project.

[All options here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIgem.png)

Please help me if there is any idea. Thank you.

I have tried with another computer and I can find this option, but on my computer, I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create it with .NET 6.0 or .NET 7.0 and change the line

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>net4.8</TargetFramework>
```

in the newly created csproj file.